# ¿Como iniciar el campo de una clase padre en un constructor hijo? [JAVA]

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en la herencia de java y en este ejemplo no se como hacer que camión tenga 6 ruedas y coche 4 ruedas, o sea iniciar una variable de la clase padre en el constructor de la hija.

**Clase padre:**

```
package vehiculo;

public class Vehiculos {

  private int ruedas;

  private int pesoPlataformas;


}
```

**Clase hijo Camion**

```
package vehiculo;

public class Camion extends Vehiculos {


    public Camion () {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que leer un poco sobre la sobrecarga en métodos a través de java

Para sobreescribir un atributo de la clase padre a través del constructor, este tendría que tener un constructor de la siguiente forma.

```
public class Vehiculos {

  private int ruedas;

  private int pesoPlataformas;ç

  protected Vehículos(int ruedas) {
      this.ruedas = ruedas;
  }


}
```

El constructor es definido como protected para que solo pueda ser accesible desde las clases que heredan de Vehículos.

Una vez hecho esto, tendrías que sobrecargas el constructor de la siguiente forma en tu constructor hijo

```
public class Camion extends Vehiculos {


    public Camion () {
        super(4)

    }
}
```

Aquí estas indicado que se llenará el constructor de la clase padre, en este caso `Vehiculos`

Otra forma sería a través de getters an setters

```
 public class Vehiculos {

      private int ruedas;

      private int pesoPlataformas;ç

      protected setRuedas(int ruedas) {
          this.ruedas = ruedas;
      }


    }
```

Luego haces el llamado

```
public class Camion extends Vehiculos {


    public Camion () {
        super(4)

    }

    public setRuedasVehiculo(int ruedas) {
        this.setRuedas(int ruedas)
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.